# Stop Audio Tag HTML5 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, audio, html5-audio

hello I'm trying to let this audio stop, but I can't find any way to do so:

```
$('<audio id="elevator" autoplay loop preload="auto" autobuffer><source src="elevator.mp3" /><source src="elevator.ogg" /></audio>').appendTo('body');

$('#elevator').pause();
```

Answer (score 7):

`pause()` is not a jQuery method, you should first convert the jQuery object to a raw DOM element and then call the `pause()` method,  try this:

```
$('#elevator')[0].pause();
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('elevator').pause()
```

or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].pause()
```

Comment: I'm trying from the console. I tried all the possibilities from chrome, but none works.

Comment: @silviolor this sounds weird as I have tested all of them in chrome's console and they work.

Comment: weird, if i do ‘play()’ it starts the track while another instance is playing

Comment: @silviolor do you have other audio tags in the page? note that `[0]` refers to the first audio element in the page.

Comment: could be something with autoplay?

Comment: @silviolor no, it can't prevent calling the pause() method, do you get any error on the console?

Comment: @silviolor try to add the audio to the page without using Javascript and try the code.

Comment: @silviolor try to call the pause after document is ready, `$(doument).ready(function(){ // your codes here})`